# Print screen in email

Tags: microsoft-outlook, screenshot

Many times when I am trying to explain something, I am creating a print screen from a Web page (or other region of my screen), cut some area and mark some fragments (for example by red lines).

In most cases I am doing this operations in simple graphic editor (for example MS Paint) and copy/paste it to e-mail program.

Is there any plug-in for mail programs (Outlook, Thunderbird) which can simplify this operation?  For example by adding - "attach print screen" - after clicking on it you can select a region of your screen and in the next step mark some fragments.

Comment: I dread the bloated emails containing images instead of a little clear text.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 7, press Start and search for 'snipping tool'. This will provide the partial capture and basic editing you require.

Even without this, you can press ALT+Printscreen to capture only the current active window.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Google Chrome browser, the 'Awesome Screenshot' plug-in will allow you to take a screen capture of either the visible portion of a page, an entire page, or a selected area of the page.  Once the screen shot is taken, it will bring you right into an editor where you can perform any marking/annotating you wish, and finally once you have it edited to your liking it will give bring you to a page where you can copy/paste or save your final draft of the shot.
Hope this helps!

Link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce?hl=en-US

Answer (score 0):

"FastStone Capture" (shareware) has the option to send output to your (default) email client (among other places).
(And can do editing & any number of other nice things.)

http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm

http://www.faststone.org/Images/CapturePanel.gif[image]